# Where_in statement in a query built with codeigniter with an string that should be an array

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-3, where-in

Problem with CodeIgniter in a `where_in` clause for a query.

Let's have a look on the query to describe the problem:

```
WHERE `table`.`table_row` IN ('7296 ,7314 {and so on});
```

This is the result of my query  in CodeIgniter (expression engine) is

```
$sql = ee()->db->where_in('table.table_row', $entry_ids);
```

My array `$entry_ids` is a string, that I obtained previously in my code:

```
$entry_ids = $ee->TMPL->fetch_param('e_id');
```

To work my query should be:

```
WHERE `table`.`table_row` IN ('7296' ,'7314' {and so on});
```

I've already try to specify that my array is actually an array, not a string:

```
$entry_ids[] = $ee->TMPL->fetch_param('e_id');
```

But actually, nothing changed.

Comment: what error you got ? pls share your whole code

Comment: There's no comma to separate each value, or there's a comma at the beginning and at the end of the list (of numbers)

Comment: what sort of string just show an example so it will be easy to rectify the problem

Comment: WHERE `table`.`table_row` IN ('7296 ,7314') is going to fail because it won't return anything.

As I said it should be WHERE `table`.`table_row` IN ('7296' ,'7314') or
WHERE `table`.`table_row` IN (7296 ,7314)

Comment: see this : https://eval.in/1019052

Comment: It's a good answer, why didn't you post it, so I would have marked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have list of ids stored as a string, which you want to query off of as an IN statement.

First split your string into an array:
If your ids are separated by a string:

```
$id_array = explode(" ", $string_of_ids);
```

If your ids are separated by commas:

```
$id_array = explode(",", $string_of_ids);
```

If your ids are separated by commas and single quotes:

```
$id_array = explode("','", $string_of_ids);
```

Then you can pass $id_array into your query:
If your id column is of type int:

```
$this->db->where_in('table.table_row', $id_array);
```

If your id column is of type string:
Just add single quotes to your ids:

```
$id_array = "'" . join("','", $id_array) . "'";
$this->db->where_in('table.table_row', $id_array);
```

Then again, if your $string_of_ids contain quotes around your ids, you could probably skip a step by just doing:

```
$id_array = explode(",", $string_of_ids);
```

That should leave your quotes in place, so you don't have to join again.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you:**

Use `explode` to get your string into an array

```
  $string = '7296 ,7314'; // string of ids
  $entry_ids = explode(',', $string);
  //print_r($entry_ids);

  $this->db->where_in('table.table_row',$entry_ids); //use in where clause
```

Working demo:https://eval.in/1019052

For more http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php